# Google Visualization legend format Jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, google-visualization

I've got an issue when using the Google Visualization api line chart with Jquery ui tabs.

I've got two graphs on two tabs. The first graph, which is visible by default displays fine:
[image]

the second chart on the hidden tab seems to be messing up the key:
[image]

I've tried changing the options but nothing I do seems to make any difference. Here are my options:

```
options = { 'title': title,
            titleTextStyle: { color: color, fontSize: 20 },
                'width': 950,
                'height': 400,
                hAxis: {
                    minorGridlines: {
                        count: x
                    }
                },
                chartArea:
                {
                    width: 880
                },
                legend: { position: 'bottom',
                    textStyle: { fontSize: 10 }
                }
            };
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(divId));
            chart.draw(data, options);
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

any thoughts on what is causing this and how to prevent it??

**Edit**

If I remove the `tabs()` call it displays correctly. As per answer below from @Vipul tried setting the div to a fixed width, no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try

1. Setting fix width to tab div(s)
2. Draw the charts first then create the tabs.

   setTimeout( function(){  /* write your code to create tabs there */},300);

Comment: Tried that, see above, no difference. If I remove the tabs() call it works fine. Seems to be an incompatibillity with the visualization api and the tabs.

Comment: try to introduce some delay in creating the tabs.  see setTimeout

Comment: It's a bit dirty but it works and that'll do me as I have more important things to be doing!! :) Cheers!

Comment: yes its dirty, you can move this code to any event/callback which fire /executes on completion of chart. You may need to dig Google Visualization API

Comment: yes might play with that, think there is a "chart drawing complete" event.